# Задать картинку при вставке ссылки на сайт

Tags: html, html5

Вот так это реализовано в `learn.javascript.ru`, когда вставляешь ссылку в сообщения, например, или в пост на стену:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А вот так на моем блоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видимо это где-то в заголовках html прописывается для индексации сайта роботами, но не нашел информации по этому поводу. Как это делается-то?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать протокол `OPEN GRAPH`, как пример (для различных систем)

```
<head>
<meta property="og:type" content="profile"/>
<meta property="profile:first_name" content="Имя"/>
<meta property="profile:last_name" content="Фамилия"/>
<meta property="profile:username" content="Ник"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Название страницы"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Описание"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://website.com/image250X250.png"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.site.com"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Название сайта"/>
<meta property="og:see_also" content="http://www.website.com"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="Facebook_ID"/>



<meta itemprop="name" content="Название сайта"/>
<meta itemprop="description" content="Описание сайта"/>
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://website.com/image250X250.png"/>

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>  <!-- Тип окна -->
<meta name="twitter:site" content="Название сайта"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Название страницы">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Описание"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="автор"/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://website.com/image250X250.png"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="website.com"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, такие штуки задаются через мета-теги для микроразметки. Изображение задается через `itemprop="image"`:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://your-link.png">
```